# Ansible integration with Rational Team Concert

Tags: ansible, integration, rtc, bigdata

We are working on bigdata and using RTC to check in our code. We are using Ansible to deploy our code which deploying the package from nexus to the target server. It also involves executing SQL scripts which are checked into RTC. My question is how can i integrate Ansible with RTC as i do not think there is any module of Ansible which supports this? i want my ansible to pick sql scripts from RTC and execute it on target database. How can i achieve this? If its not possible, what else shud i try?

Thanks
Abhishek Somani

Answer (score 0):

As long as your target server has the [Build System Toolkit](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.jazz.install.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_install_build_toolkit.html), it has as its disposal commands like **[scm load](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/load.html&scope=null)**.

That `scm load` command ca be used to [download files or file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42711270/6309), and can be called from an Ansible ssh session.