# How to download a file from IBM Jazz revision control server using ant task?

Tags: version-control, revision, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

I am very new to IBM Jazz, i have downloaded RTC-BuildSystem-Toolkit which includes eclipse plugin and ant build task definitions. My question is how to download/fetch a file from Jazz server?

Do i have to use teamFetch anttask?

```
<teamFetch repositoryAddress="https://dev.1-gateway.org/ccm/"
                       userId="u12345"
                       password="p12345"
                       workspaceName="??"
                       buildResultUUID="??"
                       destination="??"
                       verbose="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [`Teamfetch`](https://hub.jazz.net/clmhelp/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.build.doc/topics/r_teamfetch.html&scope=null), I would rather try the (non-ant) command [`scm load`](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/load.html&scope=null), which is the command-line equivalent of the GUI action:

> Right-click on the component of the repository workspace ->
>   context menu show ->
>   repository file,
>   in the view, rigth-click on the file ->
>   context menu load or load as...

See [this example](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/125536/how-load-only-one-file-within-a-component-with-scm-load):

> ```
> c:\test>scm ls comp 1151
> Workspace: (1151) "commandline" <-> (1147) "cli"
>   Component: (1152) "commandline Default Component"
>   Component: (1166) "Test Cases" 
>
> c:\test>scm ls rf -r ella 1151 1152 --depth -
> /
> /CliTest2/
> /CliTest2/CommandLine_Readme3.txt
> /CliTest2/CommandLine_Readme2.txt
> /CliTest2/CommandLine_Readme1.txt
> /CliTest3/
> /CliTest3/CommandLine_Readme3.txt
> /CliTest3/CommandLine_Readme2.txt
> /CliTest3/CommandLine_Readme1.txt
> ```
>
> 1151 is the workspace alias and 1152 is the component alias.
>   You can also specify the name or uuid instead of alias for each of these items.
>
> Remote path with component name included in the remotepath:
>
> ```
> c:\test\load>scm load 1151 "commandline Default Component/CliTest2/CommandLine_Readme3.txt"
> Successfully loaded items into the sandbox.
> ```
>
> Remote path with component alias included in the remotepath:
>
> ```
> c:\test\load>scm load 1151 1152/CliTest2/CommandLine_Readme2.txt
> Successfully loaded items into the sandbox.
> ```
>
> Note: Aliases are temporary and should not be used in scripts.